# Pass props from class component to stateless component

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, react-props

Happy new year!
I am trying to use a class child component into a functional component and I can't figure it out how to use props with it.
I am having a Picture class component that I am importing in my SignUp stateless component in order for the user to upload a picture together with other credentials and create a new user profile.

This is my Picture component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Picture extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        file:null
    }

    this.getFiles = this.getFiles.bind(this);
}

getFiles = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log("filess::", file)
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const url= reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        console.log("event::", e)
        console.log("result::",e.target.result)
        console.log("readerRes::", reader.result);
        this.props.cb(reader.result);
      this.setState({
          file:reader.result
      })
    };
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
       Add Pic <input type="file" name="image" multiple={true} onChange={this.getFiles}/><br/>
        <img src={this.state.file} height="100"/>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I need to import this child component and use it in my SignUp stateless component and I can't figure it out how.
You can find below my functional component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import Picture from './picture.js'

const signUpSchema = yup.object({
    nume: yup.string()
                .required()
                .min(4),
    email: yup.string()
                .required()
                .min(5),    
    password: yup.string()
                .required()
                .min(2), 
    picture: yup.string()
                .required()
                .min(5),
    passwordConfirmation: yup.string()
                .required()
                .oneOf([yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords must match'), 
});

function SignUp(props) {
    console.log("signUpProps::", props);
    let [esteUserAdaugat, seteazaUserulAdaugat] = React.useState(false);
    const addUserInDb = async (userDetails) => {
    console.log('is submit working:: ', userDetails);
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({...userDetails, pisici: []})
    });
    if( response.status === 400){
        seteazaUserulAdaugat(false);
    }
    if (response.status === 200) {
        seteazaUserulAdaugat(true);
        props.history.push("/users/")
    }
};
const initialValues ={
    nume: '',
    email: '', 
    password: '',
    picture:'',
    pisici:[],
    passwordConfirmation:''    
};
return (
  <div>
    Signup page
    <Formik 
        initialValues={
            initialValues
        }
        validationSchema={signUpSchema}
        onSubmit={(values, {resetForm})=>{
            addUserInDb(values);
            // getPic(pic);
            resetForm();
        }}
    >
        {
            (props) => {
                return (
                    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                            value={props.values.nume}
                            name="nume"
                            placeholder="name"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                            value={props.values.email}
                            name="email"
                            placeholder="email address"
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                            value={props.values.password}
                            name="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                        />    
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            onChange={props.handleChange}
                            onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                            value={props.values.passwordConfirmation}
                            name="passwordConfirmation"
                            placeholder="Re-type password"
                        />                                                      
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                        <div>{props.touched.nume && props.errors.nume}</div>
                        <div>{props.touched.email && props.errors.email}</div>
                        <div>{props.touched.password && props.errors.password}</div>
                        <div>{props.touched.passwordConfirmation && props.errors.passwordConfirmation}</div>

                        <ConfirmareAdaugareUserComponent wasUserAdded={esteUserAdaugat}/>                
                    </form>
                );
            }
        }
    </Formik>
  </div>

 );
}

export default SignUp;
  
function ConfirmareAdaugareUserComponent(props){
    const wasUserAdded = props.wasUserAdded;
    let confirmationValue = '';
    if (wasUserAdded) {
        confirmationValue = 'Userul a fost adaugat';
    } else {
        confirmationValue = "Please fill in the form to sign up."
    }
    return(
        <div>{confirmationValue}</div>
    );
}
```

Any help or tip is greatly valued.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I made this for myself I'll show you how I did this:

My picture schema :

```
image_select: Yup.mixed().test(
  "fileSize",
  `File too large ,should be lower than ${Math.floor(FILE_SIZE / 1000)}kb`,
  (value) =>
    value && typeof value === "object" ? value.size <= FILE_SIZE : true
);
```

For putting that on the form you should use Formik `Field` (also recommend for another input use that):

```
<Field
  name="image_select"
  component={Picture}
  image={initialValues.image_select}
  setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
  margin="normal"
  errorMessage={errors["image_select"] ? errors["image_select"] : undefined}
/>
```

And in your `Picture` component you should get props like this:

```
const { errorMessage, classes, image, field } = this.props;
```

Also set ImageValue with this function after get file:

```
this.props.setFieldValue(this.props.field.name, file);
```